# Stuttering videos at VLC, streaming from file

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I'm having constant problems with files stuttering while watching them.

http://puu.sh/jJ7Zh/25c40e2bf0.jpg (can't post pictures yet :/) This file is a .mkv, don't know if it matters, but having problems with other file-extensions too.

I tried adding more ms to the streaming buffer, from 1500 ms to 3500ms, but (while it worked at some files), it doesn't seem to have any effect. 
I don't believe my pc to be too bad to actually watch a movie without any problems, and I know the file isn't the problem, as it's happening with all the movies/series I have.

I'm no geek of all the fancy codec-stuff, so it might just be a problem of such, but I guessed it had something to do with the buffer, so I searched up how to add more to it, and I found some old tips on Google.

Also, in this file in concrete, the Audio output sounds really weird, as if it's echoing. (It's a rip, so it's not a problem with the original file)

Thanks